# SEO friendly URL parameter

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite the following url

http://mysite/product/myproduct?accessories=newacesssory

to

http://mysite/product/myproduct/accessories

Thanks!
Jon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: You've already essentially answered your own question via the tags. This has been asked-and-answered probably thousands of times here.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is look at this example for creating "Pretty Urls". It involves some pretty simple modification to your `.htaccess` file, but will produce the desired results. A link to an example can be found [here](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html). There are also tons of useful YouTube videos on this.